# How can I plot 3 repeat observations per sample on a scatter in R?

Tags: r, grouping, scatter

I have a dataframe with the following columns; Sample, Read_length, Length, Rep, Year, Sex.  Each unique sample has 6 Length values (2 Read_length conditions x 3 Reps). I would like to plot Length vs Year in such a way that each group of 3 repeats is visually linked on the plot, so I can see the variation. I am using colour and point shape to distinguish between the 2 read-lengths and between Male & Female.

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Year, y = Length, shape = Sex, colour = Read_length)) + geom_point(size = 3) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 4))
```

Is there a way to group first by read_length, and then by sample name, to generate the groups of three (and how to then plot that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your input data and use group_by() from dplyr. This will allow ggplot, and many other tidyverse functions to process each sample separately.

```
data %>% group_by(Sample)
```